# Clear bubble forming on guppy fin

Tags: behavior, health, fish, freshwater, community-aquarium

My male white guppy has a strange, bubble-filled pocket on both sides of his dorsal fin. It does not seem to be affecting or causing any pain to the guppy. He is acting normal. He is still energetic and eats normally. I have never seen anything like this on any of my guppies. I have had this certain guppy for more than a year and he has been perfectly fine. I have looked this up on the internet and this has happened before, but no one seems to know any information on this. If you know how to cure this or any information about this, please let me know.

*Note: I am not able to do any water testing at the moment, so I do not know any information on the levels of pH, nitrates, or etc.

[image]